# Freemarker and Velocity Template Variables

Tags: liferay

Also asked in this Liferay Forum [post](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/73287429)

I'm looking for a list of available variables to include in my notifications that are sent via the Kaleo Workflow

Form the default workflow I see they've used `${userName}` and `${taskComments}` that embed into the template sent out - so my questions are:

1. Where are these variables set?
2. Is there a default list of variables that can be added to my template?

Thanks much!

Comment: http://content.liferay.com/4.3/misc/theme-api-4.3.0.html

Comment: https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+Objects+from+Velocity#section-Access+Objects+from+Velocity-Layout+Templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://web.liferay.com/web/igor.beslic/blog/-/blogs/workflow-in-action-kaleo-workflow-context-variables

Above is list of workflow variables which became pretty useful in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look into **[WorkflowConstants](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/workflow/WorkflowConstants.html)** class. It contains all constants which needs into WorkFlow.

Thanks