# Liferay Freemarker Variable List

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-theme

I am looking for list of all freemarker variables in Liferay.

Similar question : [Freemarker and Velocity Template Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732815/freemarker-and-velocity-template-variables) has list of all Velocity variables, but not freemarker.

Answer (score 4):

As you neither give a version nor a usecase (Application Display Template, Web Content Template, Theme or other): A good starting point is the initialization that is done in [TemplateContextHelper](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/template/TemplateContextHelper.java) (choose the branch for your version of interest).

Check the name of this class: It's meant to be independent of Velocity or Freemarker - it's typically safe to assume that both have the same values available.

And, depending on the version and the amount of work that you'd like to do yourself, you can also build this list yourself. Check [this](https://web.liferay.com/de/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/dumping-adt-wcm-template-variables) and [this](https://web.liferay.com/de/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/the-magic-template-variable-dumper-script-for-liferay-7) article.